# Why inserting an object into vector causes C2679

Tags: c++, vector

I'm sorry but there can't be an example so we'll have to take a look into the real code here.
What happens is, I have class `CItemElem` (note this is an old source, please disconsider hungarian notations, class names etc..).
As in the example below I'm trying to do the same with `CItemElem`

```
class A
{
public:
    int value;
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    std::vector<A> hold;
    A a;
    hold.push_back(a);
}
```

Althought with class `CItemElem` the compiler gives me C2679 when trying to

`vector<CItemElem>hold;
CItemElem item;
hold.push_back(item);`

`Error C2679: '=' binary :no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const CItemElem' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

by clicking at the error it leads me to this line `*_First = _Val;`
at this function on `xutility`

```
template<class _FwdIt,
    class _Ty> inline
    void fill(_FwdIt _First, _FwdIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val)
    {   // copy _Val through [_First, _Last)
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        *_First = _Val;
    }
```

The CItemElem class is too long and derived so I decided to upload it to pastebin, instead of pasting the huge code in here.
[Pastebin: Class CItemElem Header (item.h)](http://pastebin.com/Kc4LwdeM)

Note that CItemElem is derived from CItemBase and has = operator overloaded, which also passes throught CItemBase = operator. This is from `item.cpp`:

```
CItemElem& CItemElem::operator =( CItemElem & ie )
{
    CItemBase::operator =( ie );
```

Comment: Surely you can trim the definition of `CItemElem` to something smaller that you can post here. Here's a hint: the compiler is complaining about an assignment operator; pretty much everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, CItemElem is a derived class from CItemBase and the `operator =` is overloaded, `virtual` overloaded, meaning that CItemBase also takes part of the = operation, The question is how to get around with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if there is no defined assignment operator (`=`) for `CItemElem`. The STL containers (e.g.`vector`) expect the things they contain to have certain properties, including an assignment operator. If you can modify the class, you can add one:

```
class CItemElem
{
...
public:

  CItemElem & operator=(const CItemElem &other)
  {
    // copy whatever must be copied
    x = other.x;

    return *this;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I see now that the header includes a declaration of an assignment operator:

```
virtual CItemElem&      operator = ( CItemElem & ie );
```

but the signature is wrong-- it's missing `const`. If you can change this (in the declaration and the definition) it should work.

**EDIT:**
If you can't edit the base class, you have a couple of options. Probably the safest is to copy the code from `CItemBase::operator=` into `CItemElem::operator=`. It's not pretty, but that's the original author's fault; the argument should have been `const &` all along.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is the real answer, it is possible to use CItemElem with vectors, I had only to add `const` at the signature! An eye of an expert, I'm amazed!

Answer (score 2):

CItemElem has `operator=(CItemElem&)`. This function cannot accept a `const` argument (as the compiler accurately told you) and does not meet the requirements of `std::vector` as an element type. It is impossible to use this class in a `std::vector`.